# Divide gulp-file into several files

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I want to divide one big gulp-file into several files.
Some of this files is supposed to contain gulp-tasks, others – raw functions, third files – both.
How can I do it?
I've tried to create directory with a few files, some like that:

```
gulpfile.js
gulp/
├── css_tasks.js
└── js_tasks.js
```

And then use `require-dir` in `gulpfile.js`:

```
require('require-dir')('./gulp');
```

It works well, but this method allows to use **only tasks** from required directory.
But this is not enough.
In addition, I want to use raw functions from another files, some like that:

```
gulpfile.js
gulp/
├── common_methods.js
├── css_tasks.js
└── js_tasks.js
```

And use it in a this way:

```
/* css_tasks.js: */

gulp.task('some_css_task', function() {
   var foo = someCommonMethod();
   /* task stuff */
})
```

and

```
/* js_tasks.js: */

gulp.task('some_js_task', function() {
   var boo = anotherCommonMethod();
   /* task stuff */
})
```

So, how can I do it?

Comment: I'm new to gulp, and I'm surprised that there is no simple answer to this question :/

Comment: You can do something like this in `gulpfile` > `require('require-dir')('./gulp/js') &&  require('require-dir')('./gulp/css')`. Then you will be able to have `common_methods` file in your gulp folder

Comment: @TheReason would you describe in more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [`require-dir`](https://github.com/aseemk/requireDir) module, it returns an object based on your directory structure.

```
{
  a: require('./a'),
  b: require('./b')
}
```

So i suggest creating folders for your `js` & `css` "gulp-task-files". So the structure can be the next:

```
gulp/
├── common_methods.js
├── css/index.js
└── js/index.js
```

Then in your `gulpfile` you should require css & js folder separately like:

```
const js = require('require-dir')('./gulp/js');
const css = require('require-dir')('./gulp/css');
```

It will allow you to have `common_methods.js` file which can be shared between these (js & css) task-folders & `common_methods.js` **will not be exported** via `require-dir`

***UPDATE***

```
// common_methods.js
function method1(){}
function method2(){}

module.exports = {
  foo: method1,
  baz: method2
}

// js/index.js
const foo = require('../common_methods').foo;

// css/index.js
const baz = require('../common_methods').baz;
```

Hope it make sense.

Comment: And how can I share `common_methods.js` between `js` and `css`?

Comment: @TroyHambleton using `module.exports`?